# how to get a window's direct child ( not any grandchildren) in win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

just the direct child, not grandchildren.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515%28VS.85%29.aspx)(hwnd,GW_CHILD); seems to be the trick.

Comment: Then loop with GW_HWNDNEXT if you want to find the other children (i.e. the siblings of the first child). (But remember that if it's some other thread/process's window, the controls could move around while you're doing this.)

Comment: What if the child is not a window?

Answer (score 2):

This snippet could help!

```
    HWND hChildWnd;
    long childCount = 0L;

    hChildWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD);
    if(IsWindow(hChildWnd)) {
            childCount ++;
        while(hChildWnd){
            hChildWnd = GetWindow(hChildWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);
            if(IsWindow(hChildWnd))
                childCount ++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `HWND hChildWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD); long childCount = 0L; while(IsWindow(hChildWnd)) { childCount ++; hChildWnd = GetWindow(hChildWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT); }` is a little bit shorter.